# MySql Query Error?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO saved_locations (CharacterID, Index, MapleID) 
VALUES ('10', '0', '100020000')
```

The Error is :

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'Index, MapleID) VALUES ('10', '0', '100020000')' at line 1
```

Why do I get the error? It's so weird. My table is fine.

Answer (score 5):

`Index` is a reserved word. You need to quote it:

```
INSERT INTO saved_locations (CharacterID, `Index`, MapleID) 
     VALUES ('10', '0', '100020000')
```

Comment: We're here to help. :-)

Comment: Even better, avoid using reserved words as column names / table names.

Comment: Totally agree with @Raptor